# Online markup validation for JIRA/Conflence software

Tags: jira, markup, confluence, jira-agile

I was wondering if anyone is aware of an online markup validator app for JIRA/Confluence markup? I use JIRA at work but then and now need to groom some tickets out of the office where I have no access to the software.

I end up wasting a lot of time with re-visiting tickets for formatting while doing the formatting on the go and then a copy paste would be more efficient

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Hasn't Confluence eliminated Wiki markup as of v4.0 or so? By "online markup validator" do you mean a browser accessible (HTTP/Web) function/service?

Comment: @ScottWelker yes, a web-based service that allows me to format on the go and save up on time of previewing and editing.

Comment: Sorry I can't help. I've not heard of any such thing and, again, I think Confluence at least moved away from markup as of version 4.0. Not sue what Atlassian is doing for Jira.